# Using pod lib create for OS X project

Tags: macos, cocoapods

Is it possible to use pod lib create for OS X project, the default is iOS, is there any way to specify OS X for the example project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in way to specify this. `pod lib create` uses [templates](https://github.com/cocoapods/pod-template/) to create your project. In theory you could create one for OS X. You can see some related conversation [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3005) about this.